# Let $p(x)$ be a complex polynomial. Prove that if $a$ is multiple root of $p$ then $a$ is root of $p'(x)$.

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, roots

> Let $p(x)$ be a complex polynomial. Prove that if $a$ is multiple root of $p$ then $a$ is root of $p'(x)$.

*Note:* *$p'(x)$ is the polynomial derived from $p$.*

Let m be the multiplicity of $a$ as the root of $p$. Then, $p = (x-a) ^ m h$, where $h$ is a complex polynomial, and $a$ is not a root of $h$.
As $m> 1$ then $p '= m (x-a) ^{m-1} h + (x-a) ^ m h'$, where $p'(a)= m (a-a)^{m-1} h + (a-a)^m h'=0$.

Is my demonstration correct? If correct, can you think of another way to demonstrate this statement?

Comment: Looks fine. This is true for entire functions, not just polynomials. Same proof.

Comment: @lhf thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your demonstration seems okay to me. I would probably choose to factor

$$\begin{split}
p '(x)&= m (x-a) ^ {m-1} h(x) + (x-a) ^ m h'(x)\\
&=(x-a)^{m-1}(mh(x) +(x-a) h'(x))
\end{split}
$$
This shows directly that $x-a$ is a factor of $p'(x)$ because $m-1>0$ without using the factor theorem.